# What is the formula to find the quadrilateral inner quadrilateral side length?

Tags: area, quadrilateral

Sorry if it is a silly question. I want to find an inner quadrilateral area for that I need one of the inner quadrilateral lengths. I don't know the formula if you can please help me.

Lengths of the quadrilateral(irregular rectangle) are as follows:

A > 43.8
B > 38.4
C > 243.0
D > 244.6

Now I want to know the length of the question mark I mentioned here. Because I have inner quadrilateral with new lengths as below,

a > ??????????(I want to find)
b> 38.4
c > 80
d > 80

please help me thanks.
[image]

Comment: When you give a negative mark, provide comments, please, even basic sense people don't have sorry.

Comment: Njan downvote chetealla, anallum, Padam kandet clear alla cheta. a,b,c,d onu define cheyuve pls

Comment: @Buraian chetea please check I updated the question thanks.